# Angular ngx translate in lazy module not working

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, translation, ngx-translate

I made a library that contains the translation module and that loads a file :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatMomentDateModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot
    ({

        loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: TranslateFactory,
          deps: [HttpClient]
       }
      }),
    ],
  exports: [TranslateModule],
})
```

In my application, I import this library and I also load the translation file of the application

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MyLayout
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MyLibWithTranslation,
    TranslateModule.forChild({
     extend: true,
     loader: {
      provide: TranslateLoader,
      useFactory: TranslateFactory,
      deps: [HttpClient]
     }
    }),
    ....
```

Then, this application contains modules loaded lazy loading and in these modules, I import again my lib to have the TranslateService

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    LazyModuleRoutingModule,
    MyLibWithTranslation
  ]
})
export class MyLazyModule { }
```

My problem is that in my module, I only have the translation load from MyLibWithTranslation. I don’t have the translations loaded from the AppModule.

Answer (score 0):

Here few solutions for you

First you can use

ngx-translate-multi-http-loader

AoT requires an exported function for factories

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) { return new
MultiTranslateHttpLoader(http, [
    {prefix: "./assets/translate/core/", suffix: ".json"},
    {prefix: "./assets/translate/shared/", suffix: ".json"}, ]);


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        })
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent] }) export class AppModule {}
```

Second is create

in your shared module import and export like so

without using forChild or forRoot

```
imports: [
    TranslateModule
  ],
  exports: [
   TranslateModule
  ],
```

in you app module import forRoot

```
imports:[
TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      },
      isolate: true
    })
]
```

Comment: The second solution does not work. forChild does not load my translation file

Comment: On this example you doesn’t need forChild on shared module you export import just TranslateModule

Comment: That’s what I did. But so I used forChild in a module but it doesn’t work.
I used forRoot to load a first file into the AppModule then forChild into a sub-module but it doesn’t work

Comment: I also tried extend true in the forChild of the sub-module but it doesn’t work. It overwrites the forRoot translation. I go through a service that inherits from TranslateLoader to load the translation